# Transliterate data from database in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transliteration

I have a database that has 100+ tables. All the data is saved as Latin characters. I would like to show this data in my app as Cyrillic characters. I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 in my app, LINQ to SQL component and MSSQL. I have tried/read about interceptors or wrappers (to intercept every SQL call from my app and call custom function that transliterates strings) but I can't figure it out. Is this even possible to achieve?

**Example:**

DB: Worker(Id, Name, Surname)

App:

```
public Worker GetWorker(int workerId){
    using (var db = new DB())
    {
        var worker = db.Workers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == workerId);

        return Transliterate(worker);
    }
}

private Worker Transliterate(Worker worker)
{
    //dictionary that replaces character for character and returns worker
}
```

This example works, but I would have to manually write that piece of code throughout my app, which does not solve my problem. So I would like write that piece of code only once (like in an interceptor or something similar that would work). Any ideas?

Comment: What does a latin character X look like as cyrillic character Y? Do you mean you want to convert `d` to `д`, for example?

Comment: Seems like a job for a static method in a static helper class that is accessible throughout your application. If you need it to work on more than just the Worker class, have it take in a string and return a string, then simply call `worker.Name = Transliterate(worker.Name);` and `worker.Surname = Transliterate(worker.Surname);`.

Comment: Claius Jard - Yes, that is exactly what I mean

Comment: Pierre Plourde - that is a possibility but I want this done throughout my application, meaning I would have the call this function (and re-write) from a million places, which is time consuming and not efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out that I'm always returning with a method ToList() so I've created a custom static toList method and added transliteration.

```
public static List<T> ToListCustom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query)
{
    var dataList = query.ToList();

    foreach (var ent in dataList)
    {
        var properties = ent.GetType().GetProperties().Where(v => v.PropertyType.Name == "String");
        foreach (var pop in properties)
        {
            var sValue = pop.GetValue(ent, null).ToString();
            pop.SetValue(ent, MyTransliterationConverter(sValue), null);
        }
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).